# Should I use CodeIgniter html or form helper class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

Is it good for performance or security issue to use those class as we know that HTML should be in plain HTML.
e.g.

```
<input type='text' .... />
```

is better than

```
<?php
echo '<input type="text" .... />';
?>
```

Then why should we use

```
echo form_input('username');
```

Comment: It's a "helper", means it's there to help. If you don't want help, do the work yourself, that's the only difference :) Performance overhead is negligible

Answer (score 3):

Helper functions are provided only for ease they are not necessary to use it is always better to use simple html since using helper would definitely create a overhead on server on the other hand advantage of using these function is your code becomes minified e.g read this text that i have copied from their documentation

> form_prep()
>
> Allows you to safely use HTML and characters such as quotes within
>   form elements without breaking out of the form. Consider this example:
>
> $string = 'Here is a string containing "quoted" text.';
>
> `<input type="text" name="myform" value="$string" />` 
> Since the above
>   string contains a set of quotes it will cause the form to break. The
>   form_prep function converts HTML so that it can be used safely:

```
<input type="text" name="myform" value="<?php echo form_prep($string);?>" />
```

> Note: If you use any of the form helper functions listed in
>   this page the form values will be prepped automatically, so there is
>   no need to call this function. Use it only if you are creating your
>   own form elements.

Answer (score 2):

It is not really a question of better or performance it is more a question of what you really need to do with your form, and especially with dynamic data.

For example if you use :

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" />
```

To put a default or generated value from validation it is easier to do :

```
echo form_input('username', $username);
```

For example also using :

```
echo form_open('email/send');
```

Will generate the correct link / path to your controller so you don't have to worry about it  if you move or change your application directory because it will put the correct value :

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/email/send" />
```

And so on and so on ...